# Передача параметров в метод

Tags: c#, .net

Добрый вечер.

Из документации к c# мне стало ясно, что аргументы, передаваемые в процедуры, передаются по умолчанию по значению. Если использовать базовые типы int и т.д., так оно и происходит. Но почему, когда я передаю в объект типа `List<object>` (пример кода внизу), он передается по ссылке? Что передается по ссылке, а что по значению?

```
class Program
    {
        static void Main()
    {

        List<object> arr = new List<object>();
        GetValue(arr);

        foreach (object o in arr)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("obj : "  + o.ToString());
        }

        Console.Read();
    }

    private static void GetValue(List<object> arr)
    {
        arr.Add(new Random().Next());
    }//Выводится одно рандомное число, а по идее не должно? 
}
```

Answer (score 10, accepted):

У вас есть некоторая путаница. Типы-значения действительно передаются по значению - то есть в метод приходит именно копия объекта, и если эта копия меняется внутри метода, то сама переменная, "оставшаяся снаружи" будет иметь прежнее значение. Тут все логично.

Однако большинство типов в .net - это ссылочные типы. Они **всегда** передаются по ссылке, то есть если подобный тип выступает в в качестве параметра метода, то в метод передается указатель на объект, а не копия этого объекта. Это обусловлено той простой причиной, что передача указателя (4 или 8 байт) обходится куда дешевле, чем копирование всего объекта (размер которого практически всегда будет существенно больше размера указателя). 
То есть, имея в методе параметр ссылочного типа, вы можете изменить какие-то его поля, и это изменение затронет и "внешний" объект.

Но тут есть важный нюанс. Вы можете как-либо менять только члены этого объекта, но не сам объект. Поясню на примере:

```
void SomeMethod(Foo foo)
{  
    // это изменение отразится на внешнем объекте someFoo 
    // поскольку здесь изменяется поле объекта, 
    // переданного по ссылке
    foo.SomeField = 110;

    // а вот эти изменения внешний объект уже не затронут
    // потому что здесь изменяется сам указатель на объект
    // поэтому внешний объект останется прежним (SomeField = 110)
    foo = new Foo();
    foo.SomeField = 210;
}

// ....

Foo someFoo = new Foo();
foo.SomeField = 10;
SomeMethod(someFoo);
```

То есть можно считать, что ссылочный объект передается по ссылке, а вот указатель на него - по значению, поэтому вы можете менять поля объекта, но не можете изменить ссылку на объект (точнее, можете, но изменение не останется в силе при возвращении из метода)

Comment: теперь вопрос более менее ясен для меня, спасибо.

Comment: Извините, но ссылочный тип данных также передается по значению, потому что значение reference-type - переменных - это адрес, по которому лежит что-то. А если ссылочный тип передавать по ссылке, тогда нужно указывать ключевое слово `ref`. Не путайте механизм передачи параметров с типом переменных.

Comment: Если я в чем-то не прав, поправьте меня.

Answer (score 4):

> Из документации к c# мне стало ясно, что аргументы, передаваемые в процедуры, передаются по умолчанию по значению.

Вам неправильно стало ясно. Все зависит от **типа параметра**, передаваемого в метод. Если тип параметра **ссылочный** - он передается по ссылке, если **значимый** - по значению.
Более подробно ознакомиться с тем, что такое **значимые** и **ссылочные** типы, Вы можете [здесь](http://msdn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/library/4d43ts61(v=vs.90).aspx).