# Передача параметров методу

Tags: c#

сидел я значится и грыз один ресурс под названием metanit раздел C#, после прочтения одной темы собственно она напиасана в заглавии мне казалось всё простым и понятным, но перечитав эту же главу после прочтения аналогичного раздела в книге Шиллта кажется слегка тронулся умом. Собственно сам вопрос что именно происходит когда передаём переменную по значению и по ссылке, и тот же вопрос относительно передачи объектов классов и тех же строк и типа object.
Моя дурацкая гипотеза такова что при передаче переменной по значению выполняется присвоение этой самой переменной параметру(да я читал и знаю что передаётся копия переменной), но собственно у Шилдта написано мол значение аргумента копируется в параметр,а по-поводу передачи по ссылке здесь можете уже наверное совсем сойти с ума от моих рассуждений,но я всё таки озвучу их,собственно как я понимаю что такое переменная,переменная есть именованная область памяти ну и собственно имея этой переменной это её адрес в памяти и когда мы передаём ссылку на это область то фактически говорим что вот по такому-то адресу положить такое-то значение,то есть получится так что в параметр метода будет передан адрес по которому лежит значение и можно будет его изменить внутри метода
Собственно вот немного кода так обычно лучше получается объяснить:

```
public int AdditionRef(ref int x, int y)
{
return x = x + y;  /* Я считаю что в иксе будет адрес аргумента использованного при вызове то бишь чисто в 16-ой форме что-то в духе 0x14453454 */
}

public int AdditionVal (int x, int y)
{
 return x+y /*А здесь я считаю выполнится присвоение параметрам аргументов при вызове.*/
}
```

То есть при вызове AdditionVal(a,b) в моём представлении произойдёт что в духе x=a,y=b
А теперь про объкты методов тут уже не буду прям так сильно расписывать и скажу вот как: при передаче объекта в качестве аргумента методу происходит присвоение аргумента параметру.Предположим у нас есть объект класса Person и метод принимающий в качестве параметра объекты такового

```
class Person
{
 pubic int Age;
 public string Name;
public static void ChangeP(Person p)
{
  p.Age = 18;
  p.Name = "Павлик";
}
}
```

что-то я немного задолбался тут типа метод main и в нём создаём объект Peson p1 и кидаем его в метод ChangeP и я думаю что здесь произойдёт следующие p = p1
Далее при передаче по ссылке тот же класс тот же метод но с модификатором ref и я хотел бы узначть что будет с тем параметром p ведь как написано у Шилдта,Троелсена на metanit'e будет передана сама ссылка и как мне кажется параметр p вообще куда-то в сторону уходит и работаем с той ссылкой что передали.
P.S простите что много букв и местами написано так что у вас может возникнуть желание меня четвертовать, но это дело не даёт мне покоя

Comment: Возможный дубликат вопроса: [Передача параметров в метод](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/390554/%d0%9f%d0%b5%d1%80%d0%b5%d0%b4%d0%b0%d1%87%d0%b0-%d0%bf%d0%b0%d1%80%d0%b0%d0%bc%d0%b5%d1%82%d1%80%d0%be%d0%b2-%d0%b2-%d0%bc%d0%b5%d1%82%d0%be%d0%b4)

Comment: так не дубликат же. Там говорится про референс обьекты и про валью обьекты. А тут человек спрашивает только про валью обьекты и про валью обьекты по референсу. И вообще вопрос касается больше референсов в рамках шарпа в принципе.

Comment: @Andrew, какая разница?

Comment: Выглядит оно действительно как дубликат,но суть в том что вообще происходит вот передал ты в метод аргументы и что с ними происходит дальше то? Читая выше перечисленные источники я выяснил что методы по умолчанию получают копии этих самых аргументов и мне интересно справедливо ли то что я написал дескать происходит присваивание параметрам в методе тех аргументов что передаём при вызове,то есть получается что x = a, y = b найдите это место в вопросе поскольку для меня вот это ключевое и тоже же самое при передаче ссылочых типов.

Comment: [Формальные и фактические параметры](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%9F%D0%B0%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%BC%D0%B5%D1%82%D1%80_\(%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%B3%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%BC%D0%BC%D0%B8%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B5\))

Comment: @Grundy разница в том что в том вопросе будет обьяснение разницы между ref-type и value-type. А в даном случае человек в принципе не понимает разницы между референсом и поинтером. То есть `ref`  путает его с `*`. **Вопросы принципиально разные.**

Answer (score 0):

Сам ref это передача обьекта по этой же ссылке. Если ты обращаешся к обьекту переданому по ref ты обращаешся к самому обьекту, а не к его pointer-у (адресу памяти)

Теперь по на примере:

```
public int AdditionRef(ref int x, int y)
{
    return x = x + y;

    // в иксе будет ЗНАЧЕНИЕ обьекта, а не ссылка на область памяти. Фактически ты передал 
    // инстанс обьекта а не его копию (копия передалась бы без слова ref)

    // т.к. здесь есть ref -- если ты изменишь значение X внутри этого метода, то значение 
    // икса изменится и ВНЕ  этого метода.
}
```

---

Твоя проблема в том, что ты воспринял `ref` как `*`.

`ref`  - принудительно передает оригинальный value-type обьект в метод. То есть передает в другой метод ЭТОТ ЖЕ ИНСТАНС обьекта вместо создания копии.

`*` - передает значение ссылки на область памяти (pointer). Вот в ней хранился бы адрес в памяти в духе `0x14453454` . Но шарп запрещает использование этого ключевого знака в коде по-дефолту в целях безопасности. Для его использования нужно врубить в проэте unsafe code support и использовать модификатор `unsafe` возле класса/метода.

---

А вот пример работы с поинтером ( `*` ) за который ты принял референс ( `ref` ) :

```
unsafe class TestClass
{
    static void Main()
    {
        char theChar = 'Z';
        char* pChar = &theChar;

        System.Console.WriteLine("Value of theChar = {0}", theChar);
        System.Console.WriteLine("Address of theChar = {0:X2}",(int)pChar);
    }
}
```

Выведет в консоль:

> Value of theChar = Z
>
> Address of theChar = 12F718

Comment: Меня интересует верно ли что при вызове метода будет происходить присваивание аргументов параметров то есть x=a, y=b  таким образом метод получит копии этих переменных,и такая же ситуация с ссылочными типами.

Comment: В ссылочных типах в любом случае будет передаватся референс на обьект. Независимо от наличия или отсутствия ключевого слова `ref`.

Comment: Может я как-то не так сформулировал чем ввёл в заблуждение людей которые увидели заголовок и тут же самоотверженно бросились мне объяснять разницу между ссылкой у указателем,но весь вопрос в том что после прочтения выяснил мол при передаче по значению методу передаётся копия аргумента и мне собственно было интересно как та копия создаётся путём присваивания аргумента параметру или как? И точно тоже самое для передаче по ссылке.

Comment: С модификатором ref - оригинальный инстанс передается. Без слова ref передается копия value-type обьекта. Перечитай коментарий в первом куске кода.

Comment: Ух ты, вот это прямо сразу глаза открыло.
P.S я конечно понимаю что сам от горшка два вершка но когда дважды повторил вопрос,а в ответ точно тоже самое что и я уже прочитал это уже перебор.

Comment: я не понимаю вопроса. Возможно проблема в формулировке. Короче, мой совет в следующем: 1. Перечитай мой ответ. 2. перейди по ссылке вопроса которым пытались отметить как дубликат и перечитай ответы там. Если ты не найдешь ответ на свой вопрос  ни там ни там, тогда создай тэстовый проэкт в котором 2 метода. Один принимает валью тайп и меняет значение внутри, а второй принимает реф-тайп и меняет значение внутри. А потом дебагером пройдись построчно смотря как меняются значения у переменных внутри метода и извне метода (где он вызывался).

Comment: Больше я ничем помочь не могу. Я уже расписал так детально, как мог.

Comment: оказывается если дважды спросить одно и то же, дважды получишь одинаковый ответ :)